# text does not show at the right position when use float:left in css

Tags: css

I want `#text1` shows at the right of `#video1`, `#text2` shows at the right of `#video2`, but now, `#text2` also shows at the right of `#video1`. so could anyone explain why this happens? and how to fix it?

```
<style>
#video1, #video2
{
    float: left;
    margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
}
</style>
<div id="video1">
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65706935" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="text1">
this is text1
</div>
<div id="video2">
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/67739892" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
</div>
<div id="text2">
this is text2
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should wrap your parts to seperate div with "wrap" id and float your #text #video Div in it:

```
<style>
    #text1, #text2 {
        float: right;
        margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    }

    #video1, #video2 {
        float: left;
        width: 100px;
    }

    .wrap {
        width: 650px;
        float: left;
        border: 1px solid red;
        margin: 20px 20px 0 0;
    }
</style>

<div class="wrap">
    <div id="video1">
        <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65706935" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="text1">
        this is text1
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrap">
    <div id="video2">
        <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/67739892" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
    <div id="text2">
        this is text2
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I edited your code and it works fine. First edit your **html** :

```
<div id="video1">
    <span class="desc">this is text1</span>
    <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/65706935" width="500" height="281" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
    <div class="endfloat"></div>
</div> ....
```

**CSS** :

```
.endfloat{ clear: both; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
#video1, #video2
{
   float: left;
   margin: 20px 10px 0 0;
} ....
```

Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aldiunanto/yVytK/) for full code. Hope this helps.